# How to reset the timer using tkinter

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I've been trying to make a program which will reset after counting down to 0 from 10.
It counts down but I haven't been able to get the timer to reset.
 Please help

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.root = Frame(self.window, height=200,width=200)
        self.root.pack()
        self.root.pack_propagate(0)
        self.window.title('Timer')
        self.label = Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.sec = 11
        self.timerupdate()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def timerupdate(self):
        if self.sec!=0:
            self.sec-=1
            self.label.configure(text=self.sec)
            self.root.after(1000, self.timerupdate)

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.root = Frame(self.window, height=200,width=200)
        self.root.pack()
        self.root.pack_propagate(0)
        self.window.title('Timer')
        self.label = Label(text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.sec = 11
        self.timerupdate()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def timerupdate(self):
        if self.sec!=0:
            self.sec-=1
            self.label.configure(text=self.sec)
            self.root.after(1000, self.timerupdate)
        if self.sec == 0:
          self.sec = 11

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

Just set it so that your `self.sec` variable resets to 11 when your timer hits 0.